# Dplyr: Renaming added columns in a tibble with rename() not working as intended

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

So I'm trying to rename columns for a tibble that displays summary statistics in my R code. But for columns I add to the tibble I can't seem to change their names completely

Here's the code to get the median minimum and maximum from the dataframe 'UScereal':

```
UScereal %>% #get median
  group_by(mfr) %>%
  summarise(fibre = median(fibre)) -> fib_med

UScereal %>% #get maximum
  group_by(mfr) %>%
  summarise(fibre = max(fibre)) -> maximum
maximum %>% select(max = fibre) -> maximum #remove first column and rename 2nd column as 'max'

UScereal %>%
  group_by(mfr) %>% #get minimum
  summarise(fibre = min(fibre)) -> minimum
minimum %>% select(min = fibre) -> minimum #remove first column and rename 2nd column as 'min'

fib_med <- add_column(fib_med, maximum, minimum) #append the max and min to the first tible
```

And these are the 2 different statements I tried to rename the columns with:

```
fib_med <- fib_med %>% rename(fib_med, manufacturer = mfr, median_fiber = fibre, max_fiber = maximum$max, fiber_minimum = minimum$min) 
#throws Error: All arguments must be named


fib_med <- fib_med %>% rename(manufacturer = mfr, median = fibre) #works fine

fib_med
```

I noticed that when I call `colnames(fib_med)` I get the desired result

```
> colnames(fib_med)
[1] "manufacturer" "median"       "maximum"      "minimum"
```

But when I print out / view the table I get 'maximum$max' instead of 'maximum', and the same for minimum as well

```
> fib_med
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  manufacturer median maximum$max minimum$min
  <fct>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 G              1.8         5           0   
2 K              1.33       28           0   
3 N              5.97       30.3         4.48
4 P              7.46       12           0   
5 Q              1           4           0   
6 R              1.33        5.97        0
```

Is it acting wacky because I added the maximum and minimum columns from another tibble? And is there a way to fix it so the column names are:  "manufacturer", "median",  "maximum", "minimum"?

EDIT: solved. Both akrun, and iod's solutions worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fib_med <- fib_med %>% rename(fib_med, manufacturer = mfr, median_fiber = fibre, max_fiber = maximum$max, fiber_minimum = minimum$min) 
#throws Error: All arguments must be named
```

This one isn't working because the first argument in your rename is the dataset, but you already used `%>%`, which places the left-hand side of the operator as the first argument of the RHS.

You can resolve the maximum$max and minimum$min problem by just subsetting the column you want instead of using `select`:

```
maximum$fibre -> maximum
```

And ditto for minimum. Now you won't have a problem.

In other words:

```
UScereal %>% #get median
    group_by(mfr) %>%
    summarise(fibre = median(fibre)) -> fib_med

UScereal %>% #get maximum
    group_by(mfr) %>%
    summarise(fibre = max(fibre)) -> maximum
maximum$fibre -> maximum #remove first column and rename 2nd column as 'max'

UScereal %>%
    group_by(mfr) %>% #get minimum
    summarise(fibre = min(fibre)) -> minimum
minimum$fibre -> minimum #remove first column and rename 2nd column as 'min'

fib_med <- tibble::add_column(fib_med, maximum, minimum)

fib_med
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  mfr   fibre maximum minimum
  <fct> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 G      1.8     5       0   
2 K      1.33   28       0   
3 N      5.97   30.3     4.48
4 P      7.46   12       0   
5 Q      1       4       0   
6 R      1.33    5.97    0
```

Although, frankly, that's a very roundabout way of doing this.

It's much more straightforward to do this:

```
fib_med<-UScereal %>% group_by(mfr) %>% 
  summarize(median=median(fibre),
            maximum=max(fibre),
            mininum=min(fibre))
```

Which gives you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset is not a regular one.  If we check the `str(fib_med)`, it shows that the columns are infact `data.frame` with one column

```
fib_med <- do.call(data.frame, fib_med)
```

and now with the last step

```
fib_med <- fib_med %>%
    rename(manufacturer = mfr, median = fibre) 
fib_med
#  manufacturer   median       max      min
#1            G 1.800000  5.000000 0.000000
#2            K 1.333333 28.000000 0.000000
#3            N 5.970149 30.303030 4.477612
#4            P 7.462687 12.000000 0.000000
#5            Q 1.000000  4.000000 0.000000
#6            R 1.333333  5.970149 0.000000
```